# Why does the sound die out when the tube is horizontal in this video?

Tags: acoustics

I saw [this cool video](https://youtu.be/7HlIMfYcKKM) in which an open tube with an iron mesh at one end when heated over a flame and then removed from the flame produces sound.

But we hear the sound only when the tube is vertical and the moment we make the tube horizontal the sound dies out which is kind of strange.

**So can someone explain why the sound dies out when the tube is horizontal ?**

Answer (score 3):

Doesnt he explain it in the video itself ?

He clearly says that the sound is due to the movement of air through the pipe, which only happens if the hot air moves up through the pipe. If pipe is horizontal, then hot air would not move through the pipe, so no sound

Comment: do we really need air to move up ?? Hot air expands so they could move horizontally also. Isn't it??

Comment: @ankit That movement would not be enough. You need the movement of both the hot air expanding + the convection movement of the hot air, to have sufficient airflow to produce sound